# ColdFusion Error - I am getting an error on a web site that got moved to a new server?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I moved a web site that works perfectly on multiple other servers onto a new server. We just patched the server, but I am still getting the following error:

```
ColdFusion is not defined
ColdFusion.Ajax.importTag('CFAJAXPROXY'); 

ColdFusion is not defined
var _cf_customers=ColdFusion.AjaxProx.../GlobalAdmin/customers.cfc','jsApp');
```

Our ColdFusion version is:

```
 9,0,0,251028
```

Because this site works on other Windows machines quite well, my guess is that this is a simple patch or update.

Can you help?

UPDATE --

This is the updated version of CF installed:

```
9,0,1,274733
```

Comment: Could it be a lack of access to the needed files in /CFIDE?

Comment: @Jason, that might be a good hint. How could I confirm that is true?

Comment: As a server-related problem, this really belongs on [SF]. However, to answer your response to Jason's suggestion: view source to get the HTML and locate the appropriate HTML script tag (it'll look something like `<script src="/cfide/something.js"></script>`), then try browsing to that file directly (i.e. goto `http://domain.com/cfide/something.js`) and see what it comes out as - if you get a 403 or 404 error then that's the problem.

Comment: Just an FYI - it also looks like you aren't running the latest version of CF (9.0.1).  I doubt that will solve your problem, but it might be a good idea to install the 9.0.1 updater and subsequent hotfixes.

If you are using IIS for your webserver, you'll need to either add a virtual CFIDE directory pointing to your ColdFusion CFIDE folder, or copy the CFIDE folder into your webroot (although I wouldn't recommend copying the whole thing for security, just the debug and scripts folders should do).  I don't know Apache well, so if that is your web front-end, you'll need to do something similar.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for that tip.  The problem seems to be in the mappings. Our CF Server is running and is now updated, but the CF Administrator won't come up. It's not getting served, even though we are definitely accessing the file. Do you know how we might tweak the mappings without having the CF Administrator open?

Comment: @Carl, we just did update and apply the patches. I'll post the updated version above.  Thanks!

Comment: The CfAdmin not showing up is another indication that you have problems with getting to your CFIDE directory.

Comment: Jason and Peter, thanks for pushing me in the right direction. Both of your responses and ideas were very helpful and led us to a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a MAPPING to CFIDE, you need a web server virtual directory. IE: the CFIDE dir neds to be browsable, rather than accessible to CF code.

So make sure in IIS or Apache or whatever that you have a virtual directory for CFIDE.

That said, your CFIDE dir should *not* be browsable on a production machine, really.  It's a bit of a security risk.

Comment: Simply blocking the whole `/CFIDE` directory is a bit of a sledgehammer/nut solution. The /CFIDE/administrator directory should be blocked or IP restricted, (and in doing that it's important to check /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm isn't still accessible - IIS doesn't always apply directory blocks to files), and I think otherwise only `/CFIDE/scripts` and `/CFIDE/debug` actually _need_ web server access (the latter not publically) - but in general I think it's best for people to understand what/why they are blocking or not blocking, so an explanation along those lines would make a good answer.

Comment: We couldn't get anything working perfectly until our server administrator read Adam's solution. He implemented it and it worked perfectly. Neither he nor I are "CF Administrator configuration experts". He'll fix the security holes in the near future. For now, we are up and running. Thanks, Adam.

Comment: TBH Peter, I disagree, but I see where you're coming from so we can just agree to disagree, perhaps.  One shouldn't have debugging switched on in production, so the debug templates aren't needed.  Equally, if if one is using CFFORM and other stuff that's deployed in the scripts dir, I'd home them elsewhere in production (and use CFAJAXIMPORT to point to the new location).  It's just easier to not deploy the whole CFIDE dir at all.  There's less scope for security-risk cock-ups then.

Comment: Good stuff. It was the browseability aspect that was our problem. Trying to browse to the CFIDE directory revealed a permissions-related error: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CFIDE'."

Answer (score 0):

Is your ColdFusion installation exactly the same? IE was your old server a Standalone installation or an EAR / WAR installation? This can effect where the installer puts the /cfide/ dir.

Comment: no. I don't think the previous installation was normal which is why the update failed. We are probably just going to have to reinstall.